# Can the term "vicinity" become the subject?

Tags: nouns

I know that the term "vicinity" is usually used in the form of "in the vicinity of...".  I would like to know whether the term "vicinity" can be used alone without a preposition, for example, as follows:

> 1. The vicinity of my house is under construction.
> 2. The vicinity of your right eye is swollen.

Comment: Could you find actual examples of such usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the *vicinity* of your home is an *okay* use. But, I'm not sure about the second sentence. I mean being a doctor, I've never used/heard that word to show or indicate the area *around* eyes. We always said inflammation/swelling around eyes.

I tried searching it but left with no such usage. Yes, we certainly have *altered vicinity of eye-movements.*

Using *in the vicinity of* is not always necessary.

> The immediate vicinity of the house remains cordoned off - *[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/vicinity)*

Comment: You could say, "There is redness in the vicinity of your eye."

Answer (score 0):

I think both are technically correct, but I wasn't sure at first. They sound awkward in American English. They're definitely unusual. The word "vicinity" means "the area around", but yet it doesn't always work as well in situations where you want to say, "the area around". They are not interchangeable.